# Creating a dynamic treeview in javascript/jquery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've been tasked with creating a tree-style list of data, something like this:

http://paulneale.com/tutorials/dotNet/treeView/treeView02.png

The only information I've been given is that it must be populated dynamically. 'value', 'text' pairs are passed to the webpage, similar to the 'select' html component. The other piece of information is that it must be coded in Javascript/jQuery, as there cannot be any postbacks from ASP.NET.

Could someone kindly point me in the right direction - how should I get started? I have no idea how the data is being passed in the 'value', 'text' pairs - all I know is that there are just 2 strings being passed containing the latter and former.

**EDIT:** I've tried this so far.

```
    function createCategoryHeader(value, text) {

        //Code for creatign the header

    }

    function createListItem(value, text) {

        //Code for creating list item

    }

    createCategoryHeader("year_2011", "2011");
    createListItem("january", "Jan");
    createListItem("february", "Feb");
    createCategoryHeader("year_2010", "2010");
    createListItem("january", "Jan");
    createListItem("february", "Feb");
```

Comment: http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

Comment: Have to create it myself, cant use a plugin unfortunately.

Comment: this is quite a challenge to build your own tree view, have you a good reason to *not* use a jQuery plugin and create it yourself, is it a student exercice ???

Comment: @ed: whether this is a student exercise or a job it's the primary responsibility of a software engineer and student to flesh out the requirements of a task so they are unambiguous. Often, in both the work world and academia, asking general questions will give you general (and useless) answers.  Perhaps you should ask your employer/professor/teacher a few more questions about what needs to be delivered?

Comment: @Cpfohl Unfortunately I asked my boss, but he said that at this point it's unknown how the data is going to be passed, or even the format. Just that it would be 2 strings - 'value' and 'text'. If I knew more than this, I probably wouldnt have to ask this question :/

Comment: @Ed: to me that implies that you get to define the format...whatever format it is handed to you in (after that) you'll need to massage into the format you've decided on.  So assume you're working with a plain-ol' javascript object (which, by the way, is just a key/value pair) and move from there.  For each key in the object add a node, for each node add another node if it's a javascript object, or a leaf if it's a string...do it simply enough and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Cpfohl I've edited my question to show what I'm thinking of trying out. Do you think that would be acceptable?

Comment: @ed: does it work?  It looks feasible, but it does not take advantage of jQuery very well.

Comment: @Cpfohl I haven't actually tried it yet, was just something I wrote here to see if I'm on the right track. I cant really think of another way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about dynamically, do you mean by this that you will receive a list of key/value pairs when you ask what children are below a certain node?

The best thing here would be to bind an event to existing nodes that call the server (using AJAX) and receive said list. After that, you can parse the result in the ajax' succes handler and add new items to the list by using JQuery DOM-modification. 
Slick enhancements could be to let the clicked node have some visual change or to change icons to indicate collapsing/expanding nodes.

I refrain from any specific code, since I am not sure where your data comes from and at what point in time. Pseudo code below assuming you have a list of 'top-level-nodes' and a way to get direct children of a node.

**UNTESTED CODE:**

```
// Construct the basic HTML
foreach(item in list)
{
    // Make sure ID is changing appropriately
    echo "<li class='closed node' id='item1'>Item</li>";
}
```

And some javascript:

```
// Add jquery stuff
function setupBinds()
{
    $(".closed").click(function() { openNode(this); }
    $(".opened").click(function() { closeNode(this); }
}

function openNode(node)
{
    // get items
    make ajax call, onSuccess build HTML
    append HTML to node

    // make sure to rebind clicks for new items
    $(node).removeClass('closed');
    $(node).addClass('opened');
    setupBinds();
}

function closeNode(node)
{
    // remove the UL from the node
    $(node).remove('ul');

    // make sure to rebind clicks for new items
    $(node).removeClass('opened');
    $(node).addClass('closed');
    setupBinds();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I do not know how the data is being passed either, these are the vague requirements I've been given :/ Would you know how to implement this without AJAX?

Comment: If you can't postback and can't use Ajax, I don't think you're going to be able to fulfill the "dynamic" part of this requirement.  If the data is to be dynamically loaded as the user traverses the tree, there has to be SOME way you're allowed to reach back to the server for data.

Comment: Just incase I haven't explained myself clearly - by 'dynamic', I mean that the content of the tree is not going to be staticly defined within the code. It will be dynamic in the sense that the contents of the tree will be determined at run-time - but not exactly on the fly as the user traverses it.

Comment: In that case, you will need to receive some kind of tree structure within the run-time dermined tree. Such as parent_id or a nested array like `array(0 => array('title' => 'Item 1', 'children' => array(...)), 1 => ...)` and then you could use a recursive function to generate the appropriate html. To be honest, you will need some idea of how your data is represented if you want to implement an optimal tree-generation.